# Как изменить импортируемый параметр на Node js сервер

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, es7

У меня существует `node js` файлик его экспорт и импорт 
Как я понимаю у него в экспортируемую функцию передаются параметры
Но я не вижу где это происходит во время импорта, это ведь должно произойти в этот момент (импорта)? 
Вообще я хочу добавить в массив `bots: []` пару значений, может проще подсказать как сделать это?
Но я так понимаю, чтобы добавить нужно найти передаваемый объект`action` в котором есть свойство именуемое как payload 
файл:

```js
import types from "../constants"
 
const initialState = {
 token: "",
 name: "",

 isLoading: true,
 
 modalIsOpen: false,
 modalStage: "add",
 
 currentBotId: false,
 bots: []
}

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
 const {type, payload} = action
  
 switch (type) {
  case types.SET_INPUT:
   return {...state, ...payload}

  case types.TOGGLE_LOADING:
   return {...state, ...{isLoading: payload}}

  case types.ADD_BOT:
   return {...state, ...{bots: state.bots.concat(payload)}}

  case types.HIDE_MODAL:
   return {...state, ...{modalIsOpen: false}}

  case types.SHOW_MODAL:
   const modal = {
    modalIsOpen: true,
    modalStage: payload
   }

   return {...state, ...modal}

  case types.SET_CURRENT_BOT_ID:
   return {...state, ...{currentBotId: payload}}

  case types.UPDATE_BOTS:
   return {...state, ...{bots: payload}}

  case types.FIND_BOTS:
   return {...state, ...{bots: payload}}
 }

 return state
}
```

и его импорт

```js
import {combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import {composeWithDevTools} from "redux-devtools-extension"
import reducers from "./reducers"

const store = createStore(reducers, 
 composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

module.hot &&
  module.hot.accept("./reducers", () => {
   const newReducers = require("./reducers").default
   store.replaceReducer(newReducers)
  })

export default store
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял:
Нет, вызов экспортированной функции происходит не в момент импорта. Вы делаете ипорт, а потом должны сделать вызов этой функции сами, тут ни какой магии нет. В вашем случае вызов этих функций происходит внутри библиотеки.

А вообще не очень понятно, что вам надо.
`initialState` используется только при инициализации. Если вы хотите добавить значение в `bots` в этот момент, то пишите прямо здесь (то есть добавляйте в `initialState`).
Если же вы хотит в какой-то другой момент добавить туда значение, то ищите action, который вызывает этот редьюсер.

В целом, советую вам почитать доку `redux`, он не сложный, и вам проще будет разобраться что к чему.